# How can I use a for loop here?

Tags: json, ajax

Hi I'm getting my data with ajax, they are coming with json so my code is this

```
$.ajax({
      async:true,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "html",
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      url:"http://sosacelulares.com/index.php/chart/buygeneralreport",
      success: function(response) {
      var returnedData = JSON.parse(response);
```

The data looks like this

```
[{
  "id_buy_report":"1",
  "month":"1",
  "year":"2016",
  "total":"10"
},{
  "id_buy_report":"2",
  "month":"1",
  "year":"2017",
  "total":"20"
}]
```

Then I am trying to use that data to create a Pie Chart and the complete code is this:

```
 $.ajax({
      async:true,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "html",
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      url:"http://sosacelulares.com/index.php/chart/buygeneralreport",
      success: function(response) {
      var returnedData = JSON.parse(response);

      var donutData = [
        {label: "Series2", data: 10},
        {label: "Series3", data: 40},
        {label: "Series4", data: 50}
      ];

      $.plot("#donut-chart", donutData, {
        series: {
          pie: {
            show: true,
            radius: 1,
            innerRadius: 0.5,
            label: {
              show: true,
              radius: 2 / 3,
              formatter: labelFormatter,
              threshold: 0.1
            }

          }
        },
        legend: {
          show: false
        }
      });
```

The problem is that my data are coming how you can see from a database and if i want to create the Pie Chart I need to put the data here..

```
var donutData = [
    {label: "Series2", data: 10},
    {label: "Series3", data: 40},
    {label: "Series4", data: 50}
  ];
```

It will create a pie chart with three portions, but it is static i need to put a (for loop) to allow the data create automaticly..

How can I make a for loop in that donutData code? any loop it's no necessary a for loop..I need just a loop that it allows me to fill donutData automaticly. Thanks

Comment: `dataType: "html"` <- what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a forEach to loop through it, like this:

```
var donutData = [
  {label: "Series2", data: 10},
  {label: "Series3", data: 40},
  {label: "Series4", data: 50}
];

donutData.forEach(function(data) {
  console.log(data.label);
  console.log(data.data);
});
```